# how do I remove / delete " all video downloader "?

Tags: uninstall

It's not working for me and I didn't bother understanding why, simply removed it from Ubuntu Software Centre where I previously got it from.

Now it's still on the left-side bar with all the other icons. also, I've gave a search in computer files (`/usr/share/applications/`) it's there but can't do anything

Please tell me if there's a way to delete/erase apps on Ubuntu without spending time on forums and googleing, must be a way ..

Many Tahnks.

Comment: Search "all video downloader" on the Software Center and uninstall it?

Comment: @edwin no luck, bud. it's impossible (

Comment: How did you install the application? Can you get it's exact name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some applications create .desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications`. Have you checked there?

Also, using the Software Center to delete applications leaves system-wide config files behind. If you want to get rid of those as well, you may want to use:

```
sudo apt-get purge package_name
```

In any case, you'll need to get rid of config file in your home folder yourself. These are mostly in `~` or in `~/.config` or in `~/.local`.

Comment: It's there usr/share/applications . but it's only a desktop configuration file.
and using the terminal , with the commands you gave me , this is what shows : 

"piff@Arcanum-48:~$ sudo apt-get purge package_name
[sudo] password for piff: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package package_name
piff@Arcanum-48:~$ sudo apt-get purge all_video_downloader
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package all_video_downloader "

if there's a way.

Comment: I removed it from software center but it still kep showing up.  Finally killed it with `sudo apt-get purge alldownloader-bin`